# How to transfer a dynamic table from Plant Simulation to Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, simulation

I have a discrete-event simulation model made with Plant Simulation using only networks filled with variables, methods and tables but none of the Material Flow Objects.
My task is to transfer this model into Java code.

I've began with writing a grammar file for SimTalk (the programming language in Plant Simulation) with ANTLRv4 to translate this model to Java. Then I wrote a visitor which prints a Java class for every network.
My **big problem** is representing the tables in java, because they are so dynamical(I think at least)

As an example of the table here is a picture:
[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFsTt.jpg).
The rowindex and also the columnindex is optional for accessing the cell. Every column has a data type but this can be changed with the table method setDataType like `table.setDataType(3, "String")`.

Example Method which is accessing the cells:

```
is
    i : Integer;
    a : table[string,integer];
    s1 : String;
do
    a.create; //table is instanced
    a[1,1] := "Hello" //value of cell at Column: 1 and Cell: 1 is "Hello"
    Table[3,1] := a; //value of this cell is the table a
    i := table["Columnindex 1", 1]; //value of i is 1
    i := table["Columnindex 1", "Rowindex"] + table[1, 2] //value of i is 5
    s1 := table[0, 0] //value of s1 is "Columnindex"
end;
```

First i thought about creating a class for every table but that would be too much classes and it's too static about changing data types etc. Then i thought about a `HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer, Object>>` with a `HashMap<String, Integer>` for the columnindex and rowindex and look at these if needed in the getters/setters. But there was no Type Safety for a column and i need a cast at every get.
The "best" solution i have so far is creating dynamical HashMaps with the right data type for the column - so you get a `ClassCastException` when putting an int into a String Map. But i need to cast every get also.

I don't know what's the best approach to transfer this so it's working even with "bad" code or if it makes sense trying getting those tables to java.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!
I hope i've written not too much and someone can help me with an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a table class and have it be generic. From looking at your post I believe it would work.
Generics allow you to instantiate a class with a variable say 'T' with any non primitive datatype.

Comment: Thought about it too but so i would have to create a new table object for every column because every column can have a different data type. So I think the column should be generic and put in a HashMap maybe but then same cast problem..